# How to stop bootstrap columns overflowing to next row when adding a margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See the below 3 columns of size `col-4`

I want to add a margin so the borders are not touching, however when I add `mx-3` to them the last column overflows onto the next line which is what I don't want to happen.

without margin

[image]

with margin  (how I want it to look but with all 3 columns on the same row)

[image]

I understand the margin adds width to the element - but... Is there an easy solution to stop this happening (i,e keep them all one one row?) with out changing the 'col-4' class?

I've tired setting a gutter on the row (not sure if this is right) but nothing seems to be working.

Code is here.

https://codepen.io/lewis-morris/pen/RwGdwdR

Comment: use `gap` rule css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Offset classes**. Visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns.

The row classes should be that:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
```

The columns classes should be that:

```
<div class="col-md-3 border">
<div class="col-md-3 border offset-md-1">
<div class="col-md-3 border offset-md-1">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `<div class="col-md-4 border">` to `<div class="col-md-3 border" style="margin:30px;">`

or

Please check once, hope this helpful to you

https://www.codeply.com/go/LN7xDgslxh/bootstrap-4-space-between-columns

Comment: Does this answer of your question ?https://www.codeply.com/go/LN7xDgslxh/bootstrap-4-space-between-columns

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to solve it was adding an extra level of rows and columns, in that way I was able to create the layout with the first level and then I added the margin or padding to the second level.

Please see below an example of how I solve that for Bootstrap 5. It would be almost the same for Bootstrap 4.

https://www.codeply.com/p/TVlhlZoGhm